# How to join tables and time align for cohort analysis in R

Tags: r, statistics, data-science

**Background**

I have 2 tables I wish to join in R to perform a cohort analysis. Table 1 is a large data table, with observations of hundreds of objects, and timestamps for each observation. Table 2 holds individual timestamped events associated with individual objects. The cohort analysis would be to align the observations from every object so that the adjusted time = 0 would be the point in time of the event for that object.

```
Table 1: object_id, ts, observation_type, reading
Table 2: object_id, ts, event_type, notes
```

The complication is that there will be periodic drift of the baseline due to seasonal effects. Therefore, for the analysis to be meaningful, the observations must be adjusted against the average of all objects.

**The top level plan using tydr, dplyr & ggplot2**

1. Create timestamped seasonal baseline - average of all readings for each observation type (there are 3).
2. Filter out objects where event occurs.
3. Adjust data set for filtered set against baseline.
4. time adjust filtered dataset so events are all coincident.
5. Plot results.

**Disclaimer**

I've literally only just read R for data sceintists, and have only ever written about 100 lines of code, so I'm a rank novice. Could a data scientist offer hints on the approach above to structure my analysis?

**Pseudo-Code and Plan**

To create seasonal baseline with timestamp.

```
seasonal_average_reading1 <- table1 %>%
filter(observation_type = type1) %>%
group_by(ts) %>%
filter(ts, count > 10) %>%
summarise(seasonal_average = mean(reading))
select(ts, seasonal_average)
```

- No clue where to start. First I need to search Table 2 for all isntances of the event I'm interested in, and grab out the object_id's that are affected. Then I need to filter Table1 for only the objects in that list! Is that do-able?
- ... %>%
  mutate(adj = reading - seasonal_average)
- For each object, the ts of the event will be taken, and used to adjust the timestamp of the observations. Repeat for all devices and somehow keep the data together? Help!

gplot2

```
data = time adjusted, filtered dataset.
aes(x=adjusted time, y = average of adjusted dataset)
what else do I need.
```

### Data Samples

**event**

{
deviceId: '410DF5',
ts: 1604391197,
date: 1604368332,
jobs: [ 'Insulation' ],
notes: 'blah blah blah'
}

**DATA**

```
id,ts,seqNum,rssi,type,reading
410D08,1604482547,714,-118,hum,61
410D08,1604482547,714,-118,temp,23.2
410D08,1604482547,714,-118,hum,61
410D08,1604482547,714,-118,temp,23.2
410D08,1604482547,714,-118,hum,62
410D08,1604482547,714,-118,temp,23.2
2C7568,1604482585,2,-98,hum,68
2C7568,1604482585,2,-98,temp,22.3
2C7568,1604482585,2,-98,hum,68
2C7568,1604482585,2,-98,temp,22.2
2C7568,1604482585,2,-98,hum,68
```

Comment: Hey, is it possible that you post some sample data?

Comment: Sure! I'll add it on to the question.